# Varnish Cache - varnishtop result. Is cache running?

Tags: caching, nginx, varnish

I have installed varnish cache on nginx.

When I do a varnishtop I receive:

```
   25.56 CLI            Rd help
25.56 CLI            Wr 200 84 ban.url <regexp>
25.56 CLI            Wr 200 0
 4.53 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == 66c0e5ad9d2a4b38c92035
 2.17 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == 569fe0eecdbe0c95cf38e2
 1.52 CLI            Rd ban.url (?:cizme-femei|cizme-femei)
 1.47 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == d8ecf769c08dbf3da26f60
 1.47 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == 89c15593dc05c5d33f2620
 1.39 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == 4baf38b66ed6c31e3999fc
 1.37 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == 57fef6f801287e9c53669c
 1.33 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == 50d693740b9351f17f3894
 1.32 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == 71828629f9e7fa5d156e8b
 1.29 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == f78bb62ce1668e037f32d1
 1.20 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == a44565de7954d969fa4d14
 1.11 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == 765aad49d3adc724568218
 1.10 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == 01831f7dc38e3a912be854
 0.96 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == 7d7e0380081ce812c01c05
 0.92 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == b7a4aaa9ce381fc631936d
 0.91 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == 6a14d688be3a68c5aec89b
 0.90 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == 569fe0eecdbe0c95cf38e2
 0.83 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == f62b9d5fac527948cec26a
 0.75 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == d278d298dcfd9dc895531a
 0.75 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == 04957dfe8a157986a6a17b
 0.70 CLI            Rd ban obj.http.X-Varnish-Session == dd72c7e2a56110608a897c
```

does it mean it is working?

thank you very much.
t

Comment: Apparently you have a ban in your vcl, check `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` see if you added something to `vcl_receive` or any other function

Comment: no it is all comments.. only backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are seeing output in `varnishtop`, varnish is indeed running.

The log entries you pasted are all tagged `CLI`, which are requests and responses made by the `varnishadm` over the administrative socket.

If you run `varnishtop` without filtering by tag, you should see many more items if the server is taking HTTP traffic.

Here are some examples of what you might commonly see:

```
2807.14 VCL_return     deliver
2744.29 TxProtocol     HTTP/1.1
1843.43 TxHeader       Via: 1.1 varnish
1757.00 TxResponse     OK
1756.86 TxStatus       200
1690.57 RxRequest      GET
```

Another comand you can use to watch varnish is `varnishstat` which gives you a view of many internal counters including the connection and request rates.

Comment: anybody know why I get this kind of bans? there is no reference around the web regarding bans on varnish...

Comment: It looks like you are using Magento Turpentine.  Those ban commands (varnish's way of purging items out of cache) are a feature.  You can see the Turpentine code responsible here: https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/blob/master/app/code/community/Nexcessnet/Turpentine/Model/Observer/Ban.php#L39

Comment: wow, thank you very much for this info. I really didn't know. Also I don't know if it is working... because I have no X-Varnish in header. do you know why?

Comment: If you suspect that your requests might not be passing through Varnish, I would suggest double checking which IP/port Varnish is listening on (this will be specified in the `-a 1.2.3.4:5678` command line argument.)  Make sure your requests are actually going to Varnish, and not directly to Apache.